# InvalidCastException when casting from child to parent

Tags: c#, casting

I'm trying to cast a child class to its parent, but I´m getting an InvalidCastException. My code is the following:

```
public class RepositoryMock<T> : IRepository<T> where T : ICleanableEntity
{ ... }
```

Then I have the following class:

```
public class Telemetry : ICleanableEntity
{ .. }
```

And the following method:

```
public List<IRepository<ICleanableEntity>> GetCleanableRepositories()
{
   var repo = new RepositoryMock<Telemetry>();
   return new List<IRepository<ICleanableEntity>> { (IRepositort<ICleanableEntity>)repo };
}
```

The previous code compiles but it throws an InvalidCastException.

I'm not very experienced in C#, I come from a Java world where this is possible, but I checked the documentation for C# and it states that this can be done through variance. Can anyone give me a hint about why I can´t cast from child classes to parent ones?

Comment: You're not trying to cast between two types with a parent/child relationship. Just because two types, `T1` and `T2` exhibit a particular inheritance relationship, that *doesn't* mean that a single generic type parameterized over those two types - `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` exhibit the *same* inheritance relationship (beyond some co/contravariance support for interfaces and delegates, not relevant here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IRepository<>` interface needs to be [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), via `out` in its generic declaration:

```
public interface IRepository<out T>{ ... }
```

If adding `out` to the generic signature causes other compiler errors to appear, it's likely that your cast is really invalid. For example, you're *saying* that the repo can handle `ICleanableEntity` objects, but if someone calls `repo.Add(new Foo())` on your `RepositoryMock<Telemetry>`, and `Foo` is not `Telemetry`, what would you expect to happen?

In that case, you may need to consider separating the covariant parts of your `IRepository<>` interface into a separate interface that you can use in situations where you really just want to use those methods without needing to call methods like `.Add()`.